# The inner workings of Google Wallet

Tags: android, architecture, android-pay

How exactly does Google Wallet work under the hood ? Is there any low level explanation available as a publication or something else ? I am just wondering how is it possible to store the card information to a phone then emit the signal to the pos machine. Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe the phone communicates with a web service, and that web service communicates with the POS?

Comment: @DOK no - it uses NFC... see links in my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really very general...

Basically it communicates via NFC with the POS machine - like your "real credit card" would too...

Some links:

- http://www.moneyville.ca/blog/post/1057234--10-things-to-know-about-google-wallet
- http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/launching-google-wallet-on-sprint-and.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Wallet
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication